# Resize VMware image to smaller size

Tags: resize, virtual-machine, vmware, disk, shrink

I have created an image with VMware workstration 10.0 from a ubuntu system. The problem is that the file is 146gb and the space used is almost 12gb. I tried to shrink it, resize it with  program shrinkvd, VMware vCenter Converter Standalone Client, vmware-vdiskmanager but nothing happens. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to export VM to OVF/OVA and then import with Thin disks?

This could help.

Comment: I will try it now. How I will use Thin disks? What should I do? Thanks

Comment: When you'll import VM there will be a question about disks.

Comment: I just did it but when I imported the OVF it didn't referred to Thin disks or something similar.

Comment: It worked somehow and now it is 12gb. And when I power it on through VMware workstation it becomes 24gb. Maybe Thin disks you said now it is part of the import I did of OVM to VMware workstation. Thank you